# Obtaining a SemanticDocument from a Scala source file using ScalaFix

Tags: scala, scalameta, scalafix, semanticdb

What are the steps of parsing a Scala source file into a `SemanticDocument` using `ScalaFix`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `scalafix`(`0.9.4`),

To write a `SemanticRule` , one has to extend the abstract class `SemanticRule` and this abstract class has a method `fix` with the following signature:

```
def fix(implicit doc: SemanticDocument): Patch
```

If we override this method to create a `Patch` either for fixing or linting, we will have access to `implicit` value `doc`. `Scalafix` populates this variable by parsing a single source file. `doc` represents a single source file.